# Rock-Paper-Scissors in procedural and object-oriented

Tags: python, object-oriented, game, rock-paper-scissors

I am comfortable with the procedural style, and learning the object oriented, so I have done a small Rock Paper Scissors game in both styles.

This script is in [procedural style](http://pastebin.com/czfb0uBa) and this one is in [object oriented style](http://pastebin.com/DGF3K39w).  Did I implement this little game correctly object oriented wise? And if no, where did I mess things up? And how can I improve them?

This is the code in procedural style:

```
import random, sys

def computer_choice():
    computer_choice = random.choice("rps")
    return computer_choice

def user_choice():
    user_ch = raw_input(" Your Choice ?   ")
    if user_ch != "r" and user_ch != "p" and user_ch != "s":
        print " Wrong input, Please try again.\n"
        user_ch = user_choice()

    return user_ch

def compare_choices(user_choice, computer_choice):
   if user_choice == "r" and computer_choice == "p":
        return "computer"
   elif user_choice == "r" and computer_choice == "s":
       return "user"
   elif user_choice == "r" and computer_choice == "r":
       return "n" # n means nul
   elif user_choice == "p" and computer_choice == "r":
      return "user"
   elif user_choice == "p" and computer_choice == "s":
      return "computer"
   elif user_choice == "p" and computer_choice == "p":
      return "n"
   elif user_choice == "s" and computer_choice == "r":
      return "computer"
   elif user_choice == "s" and computer_choice == "p":
      return "user"
   elif user_choice == "s" and computer_choice == "s":
      return "n"

def play_again():
    print "Game Over"
    choice = raw_input(" Would you like to play again? (Y/N) ")
    if choice == "y" or choice == "Y":
        play()
    elif choice == "n" or choice == "N":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print " Wrong input, Please try again.\n"
        play_again()

def play():
    global user_score, computer_score
    i = 1
    while i <= 3:
        user_c = user_choice()
        computer_c = computer_choice()
        result = compare_choices(user_c, computer_c)
        if result == "user":
            user_score += 1
            print " Your choice was " + user_c + ", the computer's choice was "+ computer_c
            print " You WON ! \n"
        elif result == "computer":
            computer_score += 1
            print " Your choice was " + user_c + ", the computer's choice was "+ computer_c
            print " The computer won. \n"
        else:
            print " Your choice was " + str(user_c) + ", the computer's choice was "+ str(computer_c)
            play_again()
        i += 1
    print "Your score was: "+str(user_score)+", The Computer's score was: "+str(computer_score)
    if user_score > computer_score:
        print "You are the WINNER, CONGRATULATIONS! \n\n"
    else:
        print "The Computer is the WINNER. \n\n"

play_again()

user_score = computer_score = 0
play()
```

And this is the code in object oriented style:

```
import random, sys

class Player:#two methods in comun between user player and computer player
    score = 0

    def update_score(self):
        self.score += 1

    def get_score(self):
        return self.score
class Computerp(Player): # The computer player class, it has in addition to the two  Player method, it's own choose method.

    def choose(self):
        computer_choice = random.choice("rps")
        return computer_choice

class Userp(Player): # Same as computer player class

    def choose(self):
        user_ch = raw_input(" Your Choice ?   ")
        if user_ch != "r" and user_ch != "p" and user_ch != "s":
            print " Wrong input, Please try again.\n"
            user_ch = self.choose()

        return user_ch

class Game: # This is a wrapper class for the "Game logic", it has: compare_choices method, play, and play_again methods.

    def compare_choices(self, computer_choice, user_choice):
        if user_choice == "r" and computer_choice == "p":
            return "computer"
        elif user_choice == "r" and computer_choice == "s":
            return "user"
        elif user_choice == "r" and computer_choice == "r":
            return "n" # n means nul
        elif user_choice == "p" and computer_choice == "r":
            return "user"
        elif user_choice == "p" and computer_choice == "s":
            return "computer"
        elif user_choice == "p" and computer_choice == "p":
            return "n"
        elif user_choice == "s" and computer_choice == "r":
            return "computer"
        elif user_choice == "s" and computer_choice == "p":
            return "user"
        elif user_choice == "s" and computer_choice == "s":
            return "n"

    def play(self):
        user = Userp()
        computer = Computerp()
        i = 1
        while i <= 3:
            user_ch = user.choose()
            computer_ch = computer.choose()
            result = self.compare_choices(computer_ch, user_ch)
            if result == 'user':
                user.update_score()
                print " Your choice was " + user_ch + ", the computer's choice was "+ computer_ch
                print " You WON ! \n"
            elif result == 'computer':
                computer.update_score()
                print " Your choice was " + user_ch + ", the computer's choice was "+ computer_ch
                print " The computer won. \n"
            else:
               print " Your choice was " + str(user_ch) + ", the computer's choice was "+ str(computer_ch)
               self.play_again()
            i = i + 1
        print "Your score was: "+str(user.get_score())+", The Computer's score was: "+str(computer.get_score())
        if user.get_score() > computer.get_score():
            print "You are the WINNER, CONGRATULATIONS! \n\n"
        else:
            print "The Computer is the WINNER. \n\n"
        self.play_again()
game = Game()

game.play()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Both versions

Imports should be on separate lines:

```
import random
import sys
```

---

Your `compare_choices` code in both versions could be simplified with a dictionary - note that tuples, which are hashable and immutable, can be used as dictionary keys:

```
def compare_choices(user_choice, computer_choice):
    result = {('r', 'p'): 'computer',
              ('r', 's'): 'user',
              ('r', 'r'): None, # None is a more conventional null
              ...}
   return result[user_choice, computer_choice]
```

---

In both cases, you should "guard" the code that runs at the top level of the script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

this makes it easier to `import` their functionality into other scripts later.

---

Use a string formatting method, rather than concatenating strings:

```
" Your choice was {0}, the computer's choice was {1}".format(user_ch, computer_ch)
```

this is more readable, and also more efficient.

---

```
 i = 1
 while i <= 3:
     ...
     i += 1
```

would be much neater as:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
```

or, as you never actually *use* the value of `i`:

```
for _ in range(3):
```

---

### OOP Version

All classes in new Python code should really be "new-style" classes, i.e. inherit from `object` (this is done automatically in 3.x code):

```
class Player(object):
```

---

Note that `Player.score` is a *class attribute*, not an *instance attribute*, in your current code. This is a common "gotcha" - it's not a big problem here, as the attribute is immutable, but should be avoided:

```
class Player(object):        
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0
```

---

There's also no need for the "get" and "set" methods of your `Player`s, just access the `score` attribute directly:

```
if user.score > computer.score:
```

You can easily convert the attribute to an `@property` later if necessary.

---

You can signal that `choose` is not implemented by the parent class but should by implemented by all child classes with the following convention:

```
class Parent(object):

    def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """This method must be implemented by classes inheriting from Parent."""
        raise NotImplementedError
```

---

`ComputerPlayer` and `UserPlayer`, or just `Computer` and `User`, would be better names for your sub-classes - the lower-case `p` suffix is awkward and unnecessary.

---

### Procedural version

```
global user_score, computer_score
```

is always a bad sign - instead of globals, consider explicitly passing around the two scores, e.g. as separate variables or in a single dictionary `{'user': 0, 'computer': 0}`.

---

The recursive implementation of your procedural version means that a very long game will eventually hit the recursion limit - have a go at writing an iterative version instead.

Answer (score 2):

One nitpick in `user_choice()` and `choice()`

```
def choose(self):
    user_ch = raw_input(" Your Choice ?   ")
    if user_ch != "r" and user_ch != "p" and user_ch != "s":
        print " Wrong input, Please try again.\n"
        user_ch = self.choose()

    return user_ch
```

This function uses recursion for evaluating a choice which **could** never be correct. This leaves a hole in your program where a user can enter enough wrong values and crash the program due to reaching the recursion limit.

A safer way of making the method would be to use a while loop instead.

```
def choose(self):
    user_ch = raw_input(" Your Choice ?   ")
    while user_ch != "r" and user_ch != "p" and user_ch != "s":
        print " Wrong input, Please try again.\n"
        user_ch = raw_input(" Your Choice ?   ")

    return user_ch
```